# Sorting Loop in Shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed, zsh

I have a normal...

```
for file in *
do
    #do something here
done
```

...Code.
The problem is that I want to sort the row of the files by a custom date, the date is defined in the second line of the files.
I got to problems here:

1.How do I find out what's in the second line of these multiple files before I actually run

```
for file in * do
```

2.How do I sort the loop by this custom string then?

This doesn't work but maybe it will help you understanding my problem:

```
for file in *
do
    customdate="$(sed -n 2p $file)"
done

for file in * sort by $customdate
do
    #do something here
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two loops. The first list reads that date out of the files and builds an index. and the second loop goes through that index.  You can use a delimiter to split the index out again to get the filename out of the index again.

```
index=""
for file in *
do
   customdate="$(head -2 $file | tail -1)"
   index="${index}${customdate},${file}\n"
done

for key in `echo -e ${index} | sort`
do
   customdate=${key/,.*/}
   file=${key/.*,/}
   # PROCESS FILE HERE
done
```

Comment: Well at least it sorts the files, but the order is still wrong because  my date is looking like 12-22-11 and that's why this doesn't work this way but even if the customdate would look like 22-12-11 it would still not work because a file with the customdate 01-01-12 is defenitly newer then a file with the customdate 22-12-11 but the file with the customdate 22-12-11 will be on top :/

Comment: That is why the preferred date format for sorting in text files is YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS . Otherwise you can tell sort to do things like (where 22-12-11 is in first column) `sort +0.6 -0.7 +0.3 -0.4 +0.0 -0.1` using zero based offsets. Good luck!

Comment: You can always rearrange the date format in bash too, since it can do substrings with ${parameter:offset:length}.  So read customdate out of the file, then create key as ${customdate:6:2}${customdate:0:2}${customdate:3:2}

Answer (score 0):

You should just do the two loops together, something like this:

```
for file in *
do
  customdate = "$(head -2 $file | tail -1)"
  # do something here, e.g. pipe to sorting command, call sorting function, or whatever
done
```

This reads the custom date from the file like you did (just using slightly different commands, mainly because I suck at sed). The intent is that you have the `$customdate` available at the same time as `$file` contains the proper name, so you can use both in the sorting.

Comment: Yeah I could but the files will be sorted by the "last modifed date" then and not by the $customdate right?

Comment: @Michael Perr: No, the `customdate` is read from the file, see text I added after the code.

Comment: "...so you can use both in the sorting." How dude, how?

Answer (score 0):

Since zsh 4.3.9dev2, there is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for custom sorting:

> `oe` and `o+` are special cases; they are each followed by shell code, delimited as for the `e` glob qualifier and the `+` glob qualifier respectively (see above). The code is executed for each matched file with the parameter `REPLY` set to the name of the file on entry and `globsort` appended to `zsh_eval_context`. The code should modify the parameter `REPLY` in some fashion. On return, the value of the parameter is used instead of the file name as the string on which to sort.

You can use this qualifier to build your file name list. Here's a basic version that sorts by the full contents of the line:

```
for file in *(oe\''REPLY=$({ read -r REPLY && IFS= read -r REPLY; } <$REPLY)'\'); do …
```

If your date consists only of part of the line or is in some oddball format, parse it around. For example, if you have a European-style date (day/month/year):

```
for file in *(oe\''REPLY=$({ read -r REPLY && IFS=/ read -r d m y &&
                             REPLY=$((y*10000+m*100+d)); } <$REPLY)'\'); do …
```

In any shell, you can build a list of names with the date prepended, sort that list, then cut out the dates. I'll assume none of the file names contains a newline character and none of the dates contain any `|` character.

```
names=
IFS='
'
for file in *; do
  { read -r line; read -r line; } <"$file"
  # If needed, process $line into something that is to be sorted lexicographically.
  names="$names
  $line|$file"
done
names=$(echo "$names" | sort)
set -f
for file in $names; do
  set +f
  file=${file#*|}
  …
done
```